# AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'PixelRepresentation'

Tags: python, pydicom

```
import pydicom
filename = r"E:\Codes\Python\tt.dcm";
ds = pydicom.read_file(filename,force=True)
ds.pixel_array
```

then, this error occurs : AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'PixelRepresentation'
the error information :
    [wrong reasons image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgGuD.png)

Comment: Please put the entire error message. Might be related to a bug. Thanks.

Comment: i show the errors as a picture, thank you

Comment: i can show this image on Matlab but Pydicom

Comment: Can you edit the file and set the value to 1 using a DICOM Editor then try again? will work on this later once I log into my personal laptop. Thanks.

Comment: I set the "PixelRepresentation" value as 1?

Comment: yes. It seems that it is expecting a value and python found no value. Thus the error.

Comment: I add this code “ds.dir()”, then it print this dcm file 's attributes,however,these attributes don't contain 'PixelRepresentation',so I wonder whether this image's information is not complete，however i can show it on matlab ,so I am confused

Comment: thank you very much ！！！！@ anonyXmous  Ps::Sorry I don't know how to @ you correctly

Answer (score 1):

I add this code:

```
ds.PixelRepresentation = 0
```

so My code is:

```
filename = r"E:\Codes\Python\tt.dcm";
ds = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
ds.PixelRepresentation = 0
print ds.dir()
plt.imshow(ds.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
plt.show()
```

then show this Image successfully.
this code:

```
ds.PixelRepresentation = 1
```

It is also correct

Comment: No problem. Best of luck on your project.